# 'Error in Parameters' for Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Just force-closed my Tableau workbook full of metrics, and when I opened again, I received the error message:

'Error in Parameters for command 'get-quantative-color' bad value: fn

After this, I received error messages that all of my calculated fields and even some basic date fields 'do not exist,' and I am basically left with a blank workbook.

Happy to provide more detail if needed -- anyone have any suggestions? Have been working on the workbook for a while and would rather not have to recreate from scratch :)

Comment: send your workbook to Tableau support. See the support page at tableau software.com

Comment: Alex is spot on in suggesting that you contact Tableau Support, but why did you force close your workbook in the first place?